# How do I use novnc on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, vnc

I came across novnc in a yum search, and wanted to use it so I installed. However, there is no information on how to actually use it. The novnc_server command exits with "Could not find vnc.html". The man page and --help menu are of no help. The README on github says: "Use the launch script to start a mini-webserver and the WebSockets proxy (websockify)." Which is also, of no help. The fedora and CentOS wiki have no info.

Comment: which yum repository does novnc belongs to?. I tried installing it using yum install novnc but couldn't find any results

Comment: EPEL http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL, and I actually never got the application to work in CentOS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get things working by running the launch script (named novnc_server in the CentOS install) from the noVNC data directory:

```
cd /usr/share/novnc
novnc_server
```

Alternatively you can bypass the launcher script and just use websockify directly with explicit options:

```
websockify --web /usr/share/novnc 6080 localhost:5900
```

I've just pushed an [update to noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/commit/3516bdf3fa09fe4ed1cf8af1b8e2ba85ada64758) that should allow `launch.sh` (`novnc_server`) to find `/usr/share/novnc` automatically but that will take a while to percolate into the distributions.

Comment: I am not able to have this work on CentOS. Any suggestions or pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A little more info on what problem you are having would be appreciated. Note if this is your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369727/how-to-use-novnc-to-connect-to-a-vnc-server-through-browser/ note that I just pushed a fix when using python2.4 (such as on old installs of CentOS).